# Truncate text instead of wordwrap iTextSharp

Tags: c#-4.0, itext

In my iTextsharp Pdf program, I need to truncate the text which goes beyond the width of the table cell. Actually it does wordwrap the content to the next line. Pl help provide the solution to do the same.

**Code**

```
string Value = "This is very Long Text Value";
var cellContent = new Phrase();
cellContent.Add(new Paragraph(Value, fontHeader));
cellContent.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
```

Comment: Have you tried using non-breaking spaces in the `string Value`?

Comment: Yes, Still it wraps the text to next line when it cannot append it in the same line